# How to print list of files without including the txt file?

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, window

I've made a bat file that will create a txt file in every subfolder that lists all the files in that subfolder. Is there a way to not include the dirlist.txt file when it prints the list?

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
for /r "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Test" %%d in (.) do dir /b "%%~fd" > "%%~dpnd\dirlist.txt"
```

Comment: Put the dirlist.txt in a different folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to pipe the output to the `find` command and use it as filter :

New line :

```
   for /r "C:\Users\SBRT\Test" %%d in (.) do dir /b "%%~fd" | find /V "dirlist.txt" > "%%~dpnd\dirlist.txt"
```

In this line, `find /V` is used to ignore output containing "dirlist.txt".